# What does it mean if the "upload updated article" feature is still active four months after submission?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journal-workflow

I submitted an article to the *International Journal of Vehicle Systems Modelling and Testing* four months ago. Its status now is “Reviewing”. However, in the submission details, the ***upload updated article*** feature is still active:

[image]

My question is: What does this mean? Is it now under review or haven’t the editors found a reviewer yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably means nothing. Many journals and editorial management systems allow you to update your article at almost any time, usually issuing a warning that you probably do not want to do this, as it will delay the process.

An easy way to test this would be to click on the button¹: If a warning as described above is issued, this should tell you, that everything is in order. If not, you can only know for sure if you ask the journal.

---

<sup>¹ Unless the editorial management system is very bad, you should not be able to destroy anything this way.</sup>